# Apply ltr to SearchView

Tags: android

I have following project at gitHub : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/Contacts

I have set my layout to ltr direction :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">
```

Ltr applied for every views unless searchView in another layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.sample.android.contact.widget.NestedCoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.ContactsFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior=".behavior.QuickHideAppBarBehavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:outlineProvider="bounds"
            android:theme="@style/SearchViewTheme"
            android:transitionGroup="false">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

            <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle"
                android:transitionGroup="true" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:paddingStart="2dp"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/search_back"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
            

    android:background="@drawable/circle_item_background_selector"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_padded"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.sylversky.indexablelistview.widget.IndexableRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</com.sample.android.contact.widget.NestedCoordinatorLayout>
```

When my device is under Rtl language, even Search close icon button is not shown :

```
int searchCloseIconButtonId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
        ImageView searchClose = mSearchView.findViewById(searchCloseIconButtonId)
```

Search cursor is also displayed at Right which is not what I expect.

How can I apply ltr to my SearchView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see in the layout, I am using :

```
<com.sylversky.indexablelistview.widget.IndexableRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager" />
```

In the manifest of this custom view, we have :

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

Which effects other views in the layout.